# Who loads javax.swing.* classes in Equinox osgi container?

Tags: eclipse, swing, osgi, classloader, equinox

I read some equinox code and doc. I came to understand that, at present, only class loading for java.* packages are delegated to the parent classloader(given that i have not modified org.osgi.bootdelegation property, which by the way seems to be null). Then who is loading the javax.swing.* classes. I have not mentioned it anywhere in the imported packages/ required bundles, but still it loads just fine. I wanted to know who the heck is "formally" responsible for loading it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.equinox/msg03760.html):

> equinox knows about spec'ed packages from the JRE for a given JSE level. These spec'ed packages are automatically exported by the Equinox system.bundle depending on the execution environment level you are at (e.g. J2SE-1.3, J2SE-1.4 etc.)

So as long as you define a "`org.osgi.framework.executionenvironment`", equinox should load the right JVM packages and export them for consumption by the bundles.

Comment: I had still one doubt though.
 J2SE-1.3, J2SE-1.4...etc are these the .profile files found insider the org.eclipse.osgi bundle. If so can I add my own profile, that would export say for e.g. com.abc.*. if it is possible will it cause any license issues, if I do so.
Thanks again

Comment: I am not sure about that licensing issue regarding the export of a profile. I will check that out.