# How to ask wildfly 19 to use .jar located in java_home/jre/lib/ext?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, war

I have some jar archives in java_home/jre/lib/ext. When i try to deploy my .war to wildfly i catch error **MyClass is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: org.apache.xml.security.encryption.EncryptedKey from [Module \"myModule.war\" from Service Module Loader]**
I tried the following https://developer.jboss.org/thread/196781 https://developer.jboss.org/thread/224082 [jboss 7 does not scan ext folder of jre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420867/jboss-7-does-not-scan-ext-folder-of-jre)
Any more solution?

Comment: The docs [here](http://docs.wildfly.org/19/Developer_Guide.html), as in some of your links, guide you on using modules.  But be careful - your links are 7+ years old and things change.  Is there a reason that you don't either use modules (as linked above) or put the jars into your webapp?  How do you manage a JVM update?

Comment: It's a custom crypto provider for my country which patching jdk, adding jar archives to java_home/jre/lib/ext when installing. With default app with main class i have no problem to launch these, but wildfly show me errors.