# No classDeffoundError Apache Karaf

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, hapi

I am using the hapi-osgi-base v2.2 bundle in my project and installing the same in the karaf container for my code to use it in the runtime. The karaf container already has a hapi-osgi-base v 1.2 bundle pre-installed my code was trying to use v 1.2 bundle and throwing a NoClassDefFoundError. I tried to specify the range in the import package section [2.2, 3.0) in the bundle. My bundle cannot resolve, range because hapi-osgi-base was not exporting the package version 2.2. It is also interesting it is only exporting all packages with v 0.0.0. I am not sure if it is something to do with their pom.

I tried to use hapi-osgi-base;version="2.2";scope=runtime. I still get the No ClassDeffoundError. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb with OSGI is that if you get a "ClassNotFoundException", you're not exporting it, while `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is when you don't Import it.

See this [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on OSGi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181211/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-on-osgi)